# Installing Windows 7 after Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Ubuntu, Windows XP and Windows 7 from scratch as triple-boot system](https://superuser.com/questions/41595/how-to-install-ubuntu-windows-xp-and-windows-7-from-scratch-as-triple-boot-syste)

Can anyone direct me to a link or describe the procedure of what has to be done to install Windows 7 after Windows XP. Windows XP and all its data must be preserved, so I'd like not to experiment; I don't have a backup, and currently can't do one.

Comment: This is very closely related to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/41595/. Just take Ubuntu out of the equation.

Comment: I edited my answer with a link to a tutorial on installing Windows 7.

Comment: @alex - and yes, I do mind when somebody edits questions not his own, while not adding any useful information.

Comment: One sentence of extra reading wouldn't kill you, would it now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Windows 7 on a different partition than Windows XP and you're basically done. The Windows 7 boot manager will recognize both operating systems and will take care of the rest. You won't lose any files, Windows XP will still work.

[Here's](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-7/514412-windows-7-installation-guide-tutorial.html) a tutorial on how to install Windows 7. Just make sure not to format the XP partition and you'll be alright.

Comment: Does win7 have a partitioner in its installation (the kind that doesn't delete files), or do i need to partition the disc before starting it ?

Comment: Yes it does. When you start installation, it will ask you where you want to install Windows 7. Choose the partition you want (just choose one that doesn't contain the XP installation) and choose format. From there on you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: you just have to make a separate partition for win7

Answer (score 1):

1. Buy another hard drive.
2. Install the new drive as a second drive in your computer.
3. When the windows installer asks you where to install Windows 7, tell it you want to use that second drive. This will often be drive D or E, but the size of the drive should be apparent in the installer.
4. After the install, your BIOS has the option of booting from any drive you like. Typically you press F8 when your computer is in the Power On Self Test screen, but it all depends on your computer's BIOS.
5. If you're happy with Windows 7, run the Settings Transfer Wizard under XP then under Windows 7. Copy your data to the new drive and then erase the old drive. You can then either remove the old drive or re-install it as a secondary drive for data.

This is certainly the safest method for doing what you want, and it's probably also the easiest. Mucking around with your hard drive's partition has been known to destroy data, especially if you don't do it right. Moreover, re-partitioning the drive after you decide that you like Windows 7 (or not) is awkward at best and equally likely to destroy your data.