# How to triple boot xp, vista, and mandriva linux?

Tags: multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Ubuntu, Windows XP and Windows 7 from scratch as triple-boot system](https://superuser.com/questions/41595/how-to-install-ubuntu-windows-xp-and-windows-7-from-scratch-as-triple-boot-syste)

How to triple boot xp, vista, and mandriva linux?
I've heard of someone do this but it failed , and it made the hard disk unbootable.

Comment: duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-boot particularly http://superuser.com/questions/41595 and http://superuser.com/questions/79827 -- the Vista process will be quite similar to the Win7 process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?p=184776#post184776